# Inverting a Particular Integral Operator

Tags: operator-theory, integral-transforms, orthogonal-polynomials

Consider trying to find a function $f \in L^2(0,1)$ satisfying

$$a_n = \int_0^1 f(x)x^n dx$$

Where $n$ is a nonnegative integer. Is there any method to go about doing this in general for any reasonably behaved sequence of real numbers $\{ a_n \}$?

I've been looking that this for a while and I have at least one interesting example:

When $f(x) = \log(x)$, let $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$, and it satisfies the above. Not only this, it satisfies something a little bit stronger:

$$(a_n)^s = \frac{(-1)^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \int_0^1 f(x)^{s-1} x^n dx$$

Where $s \in \mathbb{N}$. I did not derive this analytically, I found it as a result of messing around with a somewhat nasty integral, which is what made me think of the more general case. Has anyone dealt with something like this before? I realize that if we use the $L^2$ inner product, this is equivalent to saying
$$\langle f, x^n \rangle = a_n$$

Indeed this is awfully reminiscent of working with orthogonal polynomials: If $f$ had some sort of expansion 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \phi_k(x)$$
such that $\langle \phi_k, x^n \rangle = 1$ when $k=n$ and $0$ otherwise, then this could be easier, but again this comes down to solving the very first equation when $a_n$ is just a simpler sequence.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance of the [moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem).  By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$ a_n^2 \leq \frac{1}{2n+1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2\,dx,\qquad a_n=O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\tag{1}$$
and by considering
$$ \varphi(\xi) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x) e^{2\pi i\xi x}\,dx \tag{2} $$
we have:
$$ \varphi^{(n)}(0) = (2\pi i)^n a_n \tag{3}$$
and:
$$ \varphi(\xi) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2\pi i)^n a_n}{n!}\,\xi^n. \tag{4}$$
By $(2)$, it follows that $f$ is essentially given by the inverse Fourier transform of $(4)$.

Comment: Very clever. Thank you.

Comment: I am curious - how do I use the Inverse Fourier Transform over the interval $(0,1)$? Should I just do the inverse on a function defined to be  $f(x)$ on $(0,1)$ and $0$ everywhere else?

Comment: @Rellek: yes, exactly. Anyway, $\varphi$ is defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hmm, alright. I would not be able to invert term by term for $\phi(\xi)$ in its power series, though, right? Since the inverse transform of $\xi^n$ is (I think) $i^n \sqrt{2 \pi i} \delta^{(n)} (x)$, that wouldn't make any sense. Would I have to recognize the power series as a specific function and then invert it?

Comment: @Rellek: yes again.

Answer (score 2):

The $a_n$ determine the inner products of $f$ with an orthonormal basis
of polynomials: $ \phi_n(x) =\sqrt{2n+1} P_n(2x-1)$ where $P_n$ are the Legendre polynomials.  There is such $f \in L^2$ iff  the sum of the squares of these inner products is finite, and the inner products are then the coefficients of the expansion of $f$ in this basis.

Comment: I'm sorry - I've been trying to work with this for a little bit but I am unsure as to how to use it completely to solve the problem. Assuming $f$ has a corresponding Legendre series, we do not have that $\langle \phi_n , x^m \rangle = \delta_{mn}$. If the $a_n$ determine the inner product is this implying I need to add some kind of weight function? Thanks.

Comment: What I meant was, if  $\phi_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_{n,k} x^k$, then $\langle f, \phi_n\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^n c_{n,k} a_k$.

Comment: Ah, of course! Is there some kind of shift formula that you are aware of for Legendre Polynomials? For this specific case I would like to have $P_n (2x-1) = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k P_k (x)$, for all integers $n$.

Comment: @Rellek: the monomial base is not an orthogonal base of $L^2(0,1)$, while the shifted Legendre polynomials give that. For which purpose do you need an expansion of the shifted Legendre polynomials in terms of the usual ones?